# Dell WIfi Not working, after 15.04 install

Tags: internet, intel-wireless

I have clean formatted my dell 5010 and install only Ubuntu. After installing everything is working fine expect wireless internet.

After running,  lspci -nn | grep 0280 I am getting

12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel corporation centrino wireless -N 1000 [Condor Peak] [ 8086:0083]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the question, please check

Answer (score 1):

The driver for your Intel wireless is installed by default in 15.04 but is sometimes a bit tricky.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Change the '11n_disable=8' to '11n_disable=1'. 
Reboot and tell us if connectivity has improved. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if the connectivity improved.

Comment: I executed given commands but still no luck, the internet is still working very slow.

Comment: Please provide the information as outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 As the result will be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 What if `"11n_disable=1"`?

Comment: check the wireless info here [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12277500/)

Comment: @chili555 please check the output [http://paste.ubuntu.com/12277500/] (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12277500/)

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Did you check the solution?

Comment: Did you try the revision to `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`? Is the result the same? is the SSID of "1947" yours? Are you able to change to WPA2 only, not mixed mode?

Comment: Hit-and-run question!  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 power_save=0 bt_coex_active=0"
```

and reboot.